# Remote Ubuntu 18.04 server won't boot after I tried to install snapd

Tags: boot, snap

I have a dedicated server running on Ubuntu 18.04 where I have several websites running under Apache. I wanted to enable HTTPS on one of these websites using certbot, so I followed the instructions [there](https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/ubuntubionic-apache). Step 2 recommended to install snapd so I did, and then I got an error related to squashfs, so I thought a reboot of my server might help. But now the server won't boot and I can't figure out why. My hosting provider was able to netboot the server in rescue mode, so I have SSH access to the server, but I don't know how to view the logs or previous boot attempts to see what is blocking. At this stage I don't really care about certbot or https, I just want to recover this server.

Comment: How it does not boot?Does it go to ubuntu emergency mode or grub-rescue?

Comment: I'm not sure how it looks, because it's a remote server in a datacenter somewhere, and I don't have direct visibility on it. I only know that the monitoring system of my hosting provider tells me it holds on boot, and indeed I can't SSH into it until I reboot it in rescue mode (rescue64-pro, whatever that is).

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem! I guess your hosting provider is OVH?

I get through it by re-booting in "network mode", which gives me the right to log in by `ssh` and the capacity to remove the `snapd` installation with `apt`. After that, I could reboot normally.